# Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: /{}/]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-rotas

Estou tentando passar um parâmetro de update, porém esta dando erro.

Controller

```
public function update(ColaborationFormRequest $request, $id
{
    $dataForm = $request->all();
    $colaboration = $this->colaboration->find($id);
    $update = $colaboration->update($dataForm);
    if ($update)
        return redirect()->route('colaboradores.index');
    else
        return redirect()->route('colaboradores.edit', $id)
                         ->with(['errors' => 'Falha ao editar']);
}
```

***Route***

```
Route::resource('/colaboradores', 'RH\ColaborationController', [
'names' => [
    'index'     => 'colaboradores',
    'create'    => 'colaboradores.create',
    'edit'      => 'colaboradores.edit',
    'update'    => 'colaboradores.update',
]]);
```

***View***

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'colaboradores.update']) !!}
    <fieldset>
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header dark"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Dados pessoais</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        {{ Form::label('nome', 'Nome: ') }} 
                        {{ Form::text('nome', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece ? Assim sem saber que erro te aparece a ajuda é um bocado às cegas :) Se tens o $id a entrar pela função a tua rota deveria ser /colaboradores/{id} e não apenas /colaboradores. No entanto, se estás a receber um POST, porque não envias o id por ai ?

Comment: Sim, é verdade, de qualquer forma, tenho quase a certeza que dica que dou resolve o problema.

Comment: Desculpe.
Editei a forma de chamada e deu certo

Answer (score 3):

Alterei a forma de chamar a rota e deu certo

#### De

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'colaboradores.update']) !!}
```

#### Para

```
{{ Form::open(['route.name' => 'colaboradores.update']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se criar a rota sem nomear cada ação ele cria automatico ex:

```
Route::resource('colaboradores', 'RH\ColaborationController');
```

Para ver as rotas geradas, no terminal digite:

```
php artisan route:list
```

E para chamar no form collective

```
{!! Form::model(MODEL_DE_COLABORADOR,[
   'route' => ['colaboradores.update', ID_A_SER_ALTERADO],
   'method' => 'PUT'
])!!}
```

Ele vai fazer envio por PUT para a controller, no metodo update